# How to get a value of a second level JSON node using PHP from a Ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can I get a value of a second level JSON node using PHP from a Ajax request?
If I have the next JSON data in client:

```
var Data = {idJS: "1", dataToSet: "example", another:{ field1: "example2"} };
```

When the Ajax request is done, in PHP, `dataToSet` is get as follows: `$_POST['dataToSet']`, in particular, I use Codeigniter, then I use `$this->input->post('dataToSet')`. But, How can I get `another->field1`?

[Solved]:

```
$postdata = $this->input->post();
$postdata['another']['field1'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you do it with codeigniter, but you have to decode the json. Afterwards you can acces the field. This might look something like this:

```
$postdata = json_decode($this->input->post);
$postdata['another']['field1];
```

Comment: you need to pass true as second parameter of json_decode to retrieve an array.

Comment: I use json type in Ajax request (jQuery) and I don't need `json_decode` to receive data. In fact, if I use that function data aren't retrieved. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$data = $this->input->post('another');
print_r($data->field1);

// or you can do it in one line:
$this->input->post('another')->field1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ata = json_decode($this->input->post('dataToSet'), true);
$field1 = $data['another']['field1'];
```